# how to show Details using next and prev anchor link in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new to mvc and want to know how to show a details of a record using previous and next anchor tag when user click on next then details of id 2 should be displayed , and again click on next then details of 3 should be displayed. how can i do that stuck here to implement this functionality. what i have tried so far please help.

```
view 
@model Webapp.Models.Person

<div class="navi-but">
                            <a href="#"><span class="previous">Previous</span></a>
                        <a href="#"><span style="padding-right:7px">Next</span><span class="next"></span></a>
</div>
<div>

    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PersonName)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PersonName)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>


    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.PersonId }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>


Controller
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Person personmodel = db.Persons.Find(id);
            if (personmodel == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(personmodel);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

add ids to  tag btn next and btnprevious
and make ajax calls as below:

```
$("#btnNext").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
       url: 'Category/Next',
        data: { personId:cureentid  },
       success: function (response) {
        $("body").html(response);
    }
  });
 });


$("#btnPrevious").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
      url: 'Category/Previous',
      data: { personId:cureentid },
      success: function (response) {
          $("body").html(response);
      }
    });
});

public ActionResult Next(int personId )
{
   personId++;
   redirecttoactionmethod(persodetails(personId ))
```

}

```
public ActionResult Previous(int personId )
```

{

```
      personId--;
   redirecttoactionmethod(persodetails(personId ))
```

}

Comment: for PageSize any namespace is there ?? i think it's an telerik control feature.

Comment: can you please help me to implement this

Comment: this code is for displaying more than one records , I think you don't need page size when you are displaying records one by one and you have to return same view which is rendered before with a reduced id

Comment: Exactly  so can you give me that example , and can you please update that code as you are saying.

Comment: edited the answer check and modify also do some net search for exact syntax

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srN56uxw76s&index=63&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVm6S8I2xd6nYz2ZORd7X2v